# Qual o objetivo dos pseudo-elementos "::before" e "::after"?

Tags: css, css3, pseudo-elementos

Encontro muitos códigos que utilizam estes pseudo-elementos e fico "voando" quando os vejo.

Os poucos tutoriais que achei pela internet não explicaram de forma clara e fiquei com mais dúvidas ainda.

- Afinal, qual o objetivo/função deles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eles representam pseudo-elementos, que você não inclui diretamente na sua marcação, mas estão disponíveis para você para criar alguns efeitos interessantes com CSS. 
Você mencionou ::before ::after, e eles representam pseudo-elementos que aparecem, antes e depois de seus elementos.

A lista completa está incluído abaixo e deve ser bastante auto-explicativo:

```
::after 
::before 
::first-letter 
::first-line 
::selection
```

fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Observe o uso dos dois pontos, o que é consistente com a especificação. 
Às vezes, você vai ver pseudo-elementos especificados com uma unica virgula, mas que foi apenas porque precisávamos para suportar navegadores que não entendem a sintaxe dois pontos duplo.

Answer (score 4):

Os pseudo-elementos `::before e ::after`funcionam da mesma forma e  trabalham em parceria com uma propriedade chamada `content`. A propriedade `content` serve para inserir conteúdo HTML dinâmico.

## ::after

```css
.exciting-text::after {
  content: "<- Agora este *é* emocionante!"; 
  color: green;
}

.boring-text::after {
   content: "<- CHATO!";
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="boring-text">Aqui está um bom e velho texto chato.</p>
<p> Aqui está um texto moderado que não é nem chato nem excitante.</p>
<p class="exciting-text">Contribuir para o MDN é fácil e divertido.
Basta clicar no botão editar para adicionar novas amostras ao vivo ou melhorar amostras existentes.</p>
```

## ::before + ::after

```css
q::before { //Inicio
  content: "«";
  color: blue;
}
q::after { //Fim
  content: "»";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<q>Algumas citações</q>, ele disse, <q>são melhores do que nenhum</q>.
```

Funciona como as funções [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) `(::before)` e [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) `(::after)` do `JQuery`!

## Browsers Suportados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>Fonte: [Pseudo-elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos)</sub>